# UASP not working on Yottamaster 4 Bay USB3.0 enclosure

Tags: windows-10, usb-3, enclosures, uasp

My development server is running out of disk space so I've bought a Yottamaster 4-bay USB 3 enclosure. I've got 4 x 2TB SATA-3 3.5" drives that I want to use first but also squeeze as much performance but keep redundancy so I was planning to use Windows Server mirroring. Let's gloss over the fact that I'm using software RAID for now and the bottleneck of metal HDD.

As far as I can tell, whilst this enclosure is listed as supporting UASP, it stubbornly refuses to work. Before I send it back to Amazon, I thought I'd ask here in case I'm missing something basic. Here is the output from the rather useful ChipGenius USB utility:

[image]

There are currently two drives in the enclosure and they report as JMicron. Critically, they're reported as USB Mass Storage (BOT) and when I look in device manager, it's a) listed as a USB mass storage under USB controllers (should be USB attached SCSI under storage controllers) and b) it's using USBSTOR.SYS in device driver details (should be UASPSTOR.SYS). CrystalDiskInfo also reports it's using USB, not UASP.

To prove that the USB controller can support UASP and W10 is working fine, there is also a SABRANT single disk enclosure plugged into the same USB 3 controller. It's working as expected and whilst only a single disk, handles multiple I/O better than a single disk in the enclosure.

Am I missing something, i.e. it is using UASP but not reporting as such. However, CrystalDiskMark does seem to suggest it's using BOT on the multi-queue tests.

Link to the manufacturers site: [enter link description here](https://www.yottamaster.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=99)

Comment: I suspect that this is probably a case of incorrect selling as I've come across a review of the same model on Amazon where they state "This most definitely does not support UASP (see below lsusb output for proof)". If I feel bored, I'll try in on a Linux build. Have to decide whether I can overcome a performance hit as it's a nice looking unit. StarTech's are hard to come by at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

The 2 bay version support UASP, but the 4 bay one doesn't.
So sure it don't support UASP in your case.

You can choose to return or replace it.

Have a good day~

Marion

Comment: Thanks Marion - very useful to know